# Error in gradle in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, developer-tools, yolk

I was setting up  Android studio on windows 7 for the first time and I got this error :

```
Gradle 'MyApplication5' project refresh failed
Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to delete the ***.gradle*** folder in your project and restart **Android Studio.**

Comment: & also remove from your root.Otherwise steel getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

In android studio, Click on **"File"** then click **"Invalidate caches/Restart"** and confirm.
if this not solves your problem then delete **.gradle** file from your project file and restart **Android Studio**.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this experimental feature from
                    File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync the active variant